# How to add a note for an attribute in magento?

Tags: magento, attributes

I have created a new product attribute in Magento using the admin panel. But I can't find where to put a note for that attribute (that is the text that should display below the input field as extra info about it.)

Am I missing something, or is this not possible to implement in the admin panel?

This is an example of how a note on an attribute would look like:
[image]

I am using Magento 1.7 CE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible through the admin Panel.

By the way, you really should add your attributes programatically. (if you database crash, your done for).

What you need is to modify the column "note" of the eav_attribute table.

You can modify it with the `updateAttribute()` command in an upgrade script. Example :

```
$installer->updateAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color', 'note','my comment');
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question. But what file should I add the addAttribute command to then?

Comment: you have to add that in a database upgrade script. See http://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/

Answer (score 0):

hmm this might be a bit late, but anyway, I had a similar problem today and solved it in the following intuitive way:

first my problem:
howto get in the extended-search-page the attributes in the a custom order?

for this I've found something here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/11782/
-- they tell:
U might use the custom not used field ´note´ from the mysql table: ´eav_attribute´
therefor you can change in 
app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced.php
the order-by
i.e.

from:    `->setOrder('main_table.attribute_id', 'asc')`

### to:    `->setOrder('main_table.note', 'asc')`

But then, you still have the prob, how to edit the things properly, without edit anything directly by in a mysql-client; from now on, I have had your problem, my solution:

**Model**: get/set

- in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php
- grep: class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract ex
- add: best after search: "n getName"

`/**
     * Get attribute note
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNote()
    {
        return $this->_getData('note');
    }
    /**
     * Set attribute note
     *
     * @param   string $name
     * @return  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract
     */
    public function setNote($note)
    {
        return $this->setData('note', $note);
    }`

**Controler**: set

- in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php
- (o.k. this is a shortcut, I think you can add some attributes to "note_text" somewhere, but I have no plan from magento)
- search for: "default value" and extend:
- from:

`$defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($data['frontend_input']);
            if ($defaultValueField) {
                $data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
            }`

- to:

`$defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($data['frontend_input']);
            if ($defaultValueField) {
                $data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
                $data['note'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('note_text');
            }`

**View**:

- in ./app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Main/Abstract.php
- after:

  `$fieldset->addField('default_value_text', 'text', array(`
- add:

  `$fieldset->addField('note_text', 'text', array(
          'name' => 'note_text', 
          'label' => Mage::helper('eav')->__('Note Value'),
          'title' => Mage::helper('eav')->__('Note Value'),
          'value' => $attributeObject->getDefaultValue(),
      ));`

finally I've initiallized the note-field in the mysql table by:

```
update eav_attribute set note=lpad(attribute_id,10,'0000000000') where attribute_id not in(84,100);
```

where attributes with the id 84 and 100 have had already some notes.

Comment: it's not a good idea to edit the magento core files directly. Bixi's answer is really a good idea.